# how to initialize dictionary as (key,value,value) pair in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I want to store values as key,value,value pair. My data is of type

```
Key -> int & both values -> ulong,
```

How to initialize & fetch values of such dictionary. I am using VS-2005.

If i use a class or struct then how do i fetch the values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a structure to store your values:

```
struct ValuePair
{
    public ulong Value1;
    public ulong Value2;
}
```

Dictionary initialization:

```
Dictionary<int, ValuePair> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, ValuePair>();
```

Maybe List is enough, if you use int as key?

List:

```
List<ValuePair> list = new List<ValuePair>();
```

`ValuePair` can be added to the `list` as following:

```
list.Add(new ValuePair { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2 });
```

Comment: How will I add the value into the List?

Comment: @NosheenJaved list.Add(new ValuePair { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2 });

Comment: @bniwredyc Simple yet powerful..Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You can declare a class that stores both values and then use an ordinary dictionary. For example:

```
class Values {
    ulong Value1 {get;set;}
    ulong Value2 {get;set;}
}

var theDictionary=new Dictionary<int, Values>;

theDictionary.Add(1, new Values {Value1=2, Value2=3});
```

Comment: You could make Values a struct instead.

Comment: Would probably be better to use KeyValuePair instead of a custom class, or at least use a struct.

Comment: A struct could give some space saving and would be more idiomatically correct, but the difference is minor and not so important.

Comment: Two ulongs are 16 bytes, so yep, this is one of the rare cases where a struct is appropriate. As for the KeyValuePair, I would'nt use it unless *actually* the two values are intended to be a key and a value, to make code more understandable.

Comment: What does "var theDictionary" syntax mean? Is something like this allowed?

Answer (score 13):

This would be an option:

```
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<ulong, ulong>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<ulong, ulong>>();
```

If you want to add in a value: Key=1, Pair = {2,3}

```
dictionary.Add(1, new KeyValuePair<ulong, ulong>(2, 3));
```

If you want to retrieve those values:

```
var valuePair = dictionary[1];
ulong value1 = valuePair.Key;
ulong value2 = valuePair.Value;
```

Or simply:

```
ulong value1 = dictionary[1].Key;
```

Comment: I prefer Konamiman's approach as it's cleaner, but this will do without a new class.

Comment: but how do i initialize values to it..give some fetching code also :)

Comment: That would give two keys and a value. While it might work it would be confusing.

Comment: naspinski, that would seem like reinventing the wheel, dont you think?

Comment: Semantically, a `KeyValuePair` consists of a *key* and a *value*. The OP wants to store *two values*, so although a `KeyValuePair` will do the trick it isn't a great "semantic" fit.

Comment: not really reinventing a wheel, just a different approach - just sticking to base .Net types - Like I said, I would personally go with a new Class, but the OP asked for a Dictionary

Comment: @astander: If you create a custom class, you can assign perhaps more meaningful names to the member variables than 'key' and 'value'.

Comment: Luke, I don't follow your logic - no matter what you return (if you are using a Dictionary like the OP asked for), since it has to have 2 values it will be an object of some type, be it a new class, array, list, kvp, etc.

Comment: @naspinsky: If you use a `KeyValuePair` you're effectively telling the consumers/maintainers of your code that each pair consists of a *key* and a *value*, which is misleading (although perfectly functional).

Answer (score 6):

Create a Tuple class, in the System namespace:

```
public class Tuple<T1,T2>
{
    private readonly T1 _item1;
    private readonly T2 _item2;

    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        this._item1 = item1;
        this._item2 = item2;
    }

    public T1 Item1 { get { return _item1; } }

    public T2 Item2 { get { return _item2; } }
}
```

And a static Tuple class with a Create method so you get type inference which is not available on constructors:

```
public static class Tuple
{
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }
}
```

Then, when you get onto .NET 4.0, you can delete these classes because they're in the Base Class Library (and are compatible with F# tuples!).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you want to store more than one value in the value part of Dictionary, you could do something like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int,KeyValuePair<ulong,ulong>>();
```

You can use insert into the dictionary like this:

```
dic.Add(42, new KeyValuePair<ulong, ulong>(42, 42));
dic.Add(43, new KeyValuePair<ulong, ulong>(43, 43));
```

And fetch the values like so:

```
foreach (var a in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value1: {1}, Value2: {2}",
        a.Key, a.Value.Key, a.Value.Value);
}
```

Comment: Semantically, a `KeyValuePair` consists of a *key* and a *value*. The OP wants to store *two values*, so although a `KeyValuePair` will do the trick it isn't a great "semantic" fit.

Comment: Right, but I would still prefer this solution to writing a custom struct for this specific task.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 4, you'll have the Tuple type for your value, value pair.

There's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx) describing the type and the design decisions behind it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to define a class say class Pair to hold your two value, and use int as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the KeyValuePair

```
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<ulong,ulong>> vals = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<ulong, ulong>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Wintellect.PowerCollections Namespace](http://powercollections.codeplex.com) they have special structure Pair<(Of ) and collections to work with it or you'll need to code your own Pair type.