# storing <key , value1 , value 2 > pairs in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Please can some one explain me the best way to store Key in c#. Following is a sample for it.

I read about MultiKey-Dictionary and Tuples(Which is in .Net 4.0). I use .Net 3.5 and which method is optimum in terms of performance?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: @NahumLitvin: No I need the optimum solution based on the performance. I don't find the optimum solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845741/how-to-initialize-dictionary-as-key-value-value-pair-in-c-sharp.

Comment: the optimal solution depends on your USE CASE. it should not take more than an hour to implement all the suggestions and test what works.

Answer (score 2):

You can store objects of some `class` in the value of `key` instead of adding `tuple`.

Define a class to encapsulate the data

```
class SomeClass
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}   
}
```

Declare a generic dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, SomeClass> dic = new Dictionary<int, SomeClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have **`dictionary`** with a `key` and **`list`** as it *value*.

```
//List<string> listOfValues = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```